# Google Scripts Editor

Tags: javascript, html

I want to dynamically manage and update a section of a Google Sites page (think HTML).

I understand this needs to be done via a Gadget (to get it on the page), Google Script, and via HTMLService.

The Google Script Editor has a .gs tab and HTML tab for writing the script and HTML. However, I want to separately manage and update the HTML in a document on Google Drive, and have the script use that to feed the HTML back to the page.

Is there a way to reference the document to `.createHTMLOutputFromFile()`, so that I can have it use the HTML in the doc on Google Drive, rather than having to compose HTML in the Google Script Editor?  Please see .gs function example below:

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile
(replace **'Index'** with **'Google Docs URL to Google Docs HTML document'**);
```

I tried different methods for providing the URL, but the script editor can never find the HTML document using the URL I provide. If this is possible, where can I find an example of how to provide the proper URL?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `HtmlService.createHtmlOutput` and stream the text in.

Answer (score 0):

```
var template_welcome = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('welcome_template_view');
return template_welcome.evaluate().setTitle("Template Welcome");
```

that is an example of how to use an html file that is in your google scripts directory. The welcome_template_view is an html file in my directory.